# How to access settings in Rhythmbox in Ubuntu GNOME 15.10?

Tags: rhythmbox, ubuntu-gnome

Annoyingly, the menu bar is missing from Rhythmbox. You'd think there would be a button or something as a backup, but no.

Any way to change settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is - it is called the application menu and in Gnome-Shell the menu is found at the top-bar next to the activities menu option:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh. I'm an idiot.

Comment: The preferences are not there for me... see this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/NLw49Pe